# Android SupportMapFragment animation stutter after a dialog is shown

Tags: android, animation, dialog, supportmapfragment

In my Android application I'm using SupportMapFragment for displaying air measuring stations readouts. I'm using the following code to show dialog detailing current measurements from stations and to zoom to the selected station:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener { marker ->
            if (!clusterManager.onMarkerClick(marker)) {
                BottomSheetDialog(context!!).apply {

                        //setting up the dialog

                        show()
                    }
                }

                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(marker.position, 14f, TILT, BEARING)))
            }
            true
        }
```

When the dialog is shown, the animation in map fragment stutters badly instead of being smooth - as seen on the video I recorded https://vimeo.com/249396333 .

Is there a way to make this animation smooth?

Comment: Try to show first zoom animation, after zoom animation ends show dialog fragment.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg Thought of that, but there's no easy way of doing that with a map, as animateCamera method doesn't seem to provide a callback.

EDIT:
Nevermind, I found the method that actually does provide callback, will check that out.